# Get reference to layout from DialogPreference

Tags: android, android-view, android-preferences

I have a preference screen which contains a custom `DialogPreference`:

```
<com.company.project.AboutDialog
            android:key="about_dialog"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:title="About Company Project"
            android:summary="Version information"
            android:dialogLayout="@layout/about_dialog"
            android:negativeButtonText=""
            />
```

As you can see I am applying a layout to this custom dialog using the `dialogLayout` property. I want to get a reference to a `TextView` within this layout from my `DialogPreference` but I'm not sure where to get it from:

```
public class AboutDialog extends DialogPreference {

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder) {
        // Hide the title from the dialog
        builder.setTitle(null);
        super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);
                /*
                 * Where do I find a context for findViewById?
                 * ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.version)).setText("Hello, world");
                 */
    }

    public AboutDialog(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it after some more Googling. I needed to override the `onBindDialogView` method:

```
@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
    String packageName = getContext().getPackageName();
    try {
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2))
                .setText(getContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).versionName);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w("Project", "Couldn't find version name information for about dialog");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onBindDialogView(view);
}
```